# Embedded code in Razor _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working on an MVC3 Razor web application which gets it's page decoration from a java content management system.  As this decoration is shared by every page I've put the retrieval of the CMS content in the _Layout.cshtml file but I'm not entirely happy with the code I've implemented...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    @{
        -- The first two lines are temporary and will be removed soon.
        var identity = new GenericIdentity("", "", true);
        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, new string[] { });
        var cmsInterface = MvcApplication.WindsorContainer.Resolve<ICMSInterface>();
        cmsInterface.LoadContent(principal, 2);
     }
     @Html.Raw(cmsInterface.GetHeadSection())
 </head>

<body>
    @Html.Raw(cmsInterface.GetBodySection(0))
    @RenderBody()
    @Html.Raw(cmsInterface.GetBodySection(1))
</body>
</html>
```

As there is no controller for the _layout file I can't see where else I could put the code to do the retrieval.  Here are a few things that I've considered:

- Retrieve the CMS content in separate pieces so I don't need the LoadContent call.  Unfortunately, because of the component I have to use to retrieve the CMS content this isn't possible, it is all or nothing.
- Use a partial view so I can utilise a controller.  As I'd need to put the entire page into the partial that option just seems a bit ridiculous.
- Call a single static method on some helper class which retrieves the data and adds the three sections to the ViewBag.  That will allow me to move the code out of the view and feels like the best solution but I'm still not particularly happy with it.

Does anyone have any other suggestions/comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a global action filter to add the required data to the ViewBag in all controllers:

```
public class LoadCmsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.IsChildAction &&
            !filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest() &&
            filterContext.Result is ViewResult)
        {
            var identity = new GenericIdentity("", "", true);
            var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, new string[] { });
            var cmsInterface = MvcApp.WindsorContainer.Resolve<ICMSInterface>();
            cmsInterface.LoadContent(principal, 2);

            var viewBag = filterContext.Controller.ViewBag;
            viewBag.HeadSection = cmsInterface.GetHeadSection();
            viewBag.FirstBodySection = cmsInterface.BodySection(0);
            viewBag.SecondBodySection = cmsInterface.BodySection(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    ...
    filters.Add(new LoadCmsAttribute());
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution but am I right in thinking this would happen for every action?  I wouldn't want the code to execute for any partial views or json actions.

Comment: I've updated the code so it's only executed on normal actions.

Answer (score 1):

One solution:

1. Create a base controller that each of your controllers inherits from.
2. Override OnActionExecuted or a similar overview
3. Add the data to the ViewBog or ViewData in your overridden code

The OnActionExecuted code will be run every time an action is called so you may want to perform some checking to ensure that the action will return a view, etc. There may be a better override OnActionExecuting, OnResultExecuting, etc. but that's the one that comes to the top of my mind.

Another Solution:

Create a filter attribute that you can use to decorate you controllers.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

This might be a better solution if you don't want a base controller.

Answer (score 1):

*"As there is no controller for the _layout file".*
The point is that your assumption is not entirely true! As a matter of fact it is quite common to populate the _Layout page with the help of controllers. Let think for instance to the Login/Logout rectangle that is a lot of web sites...it is typically put in the _Layout and handled with a controller.
There is no controller that pass a ViewModel to the Layout...simply because the Layout...is just...a Layout and not something that convey information...howeber it can be a "container" for other contents that in turn may have a ViewModel.
In practice you can invoke Child controllers from the _Layout by using Html.Action or Html.RenderAction...This is the way Login is handled in most of the asp.net Mvc web site...and I suggest you to do the same for your content...fill your content by invoking specialized child controllers, one for each different "area" of the Layout page.

Comment: The only issue I can see with doing it this way is I'd need to pass data to all of the different controller actions as I only want to call the LoadContent method once.  Am I misunderstanding something in your suggested solution?  Is it possible to pass the state data between the different controller actions (without using viewbag)?

Comment: Probably you  misunderstood my suggestion. Probaby you need just 1-2 conrollers. The choice between 1-2...depending just on modularity issues..that it is on your choice. Just put in your _layout an Html.Action or an Html.RenderAction that calls just one controller. This way you will have always the same controller filling a part of your _layout...this means the same controller do the job for ALL YOUR VIEWS that uses that _layout page.
You can choose also to use more than one Html.Action if you would like to have several controllers each filling a different part of the _layout..it is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your answer might be here: [child action that obviates need for base controller.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4021231/1284283)